# Refresh QML Listview from Slot

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml, slot

I have problem with the refreshing Listview in QML I looked through many solutions but there is nothing concrete i want from event "onClicked" refresh all listview but how to do this?

sourcecode: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=86538244635919176055

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>
#include "message.h"
#include "dataobject.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QList<QObject*> dataList;
    dataList.append(new DataObject("1"));
    dataList.append(new DataObject("2"));
    dataList.append(new DataObject("3"));
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    Message msg;
    msg.setListInstance(&dataList);
    auto root_context = engine.rootContext();
    root_context->setContextProperty("message",&msg);
    //root_context->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(dataList));
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    QQmlContext *ctxt = new QQmlContext(engine.rootContext());
    //ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(dataList));
    return app.exec();
}
```

message.h

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_H
#define MESSAGE_H
#include <QQmlListProperty>
#include <QObject>
class Message : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<QObject> myModel READ getList NOTIFY listChanged)
public:
    explicit Message(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Message();
    void setListInstance(QList<QObject *> *dataList){ list = dataList; }
    QQmlListProperty<QObject> myModel() const;
public slots:
    void refreshLista();
    QQmlListProperty<QObject> getList();
private:
    QList<QObject *> *list;
signals:
    void listChanged();
};
#endif // MESSAGE_H
```

message.cpp

```
#include "message.h"
#include "dataobject.h"
#include <QDebug>
Message::Message(QObject *parent):QObject(parent){}
Message::~Message(){}
void Message::refreshLista(){
    list->append(new DataObject("44444"));
    emit listChanged();
    qDebug() << " REFRESH LISTA ";
}
QQmlListProperty<QObject> Message::getList(){
    return QQmlListProperty<QObject>(this, *list);
}
```

dataobject.h

```
#ifndef DATAOBJECT_H
#define DATAOBJECT_H
#include <QObject>
class DataObject : public QObject { Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY( QString title READ title WRITE setTitle NOTIFY info)
public:
    DataObject(QObject * parent = 0 );
    DataObject(const QString &_title,QObject * parent=0 );
    QString title() const;
    void setTitle(const QString &);
signals:
    void info();
private:
    QString m_id;
    QString m_title;
};
#endif // DATAOBJECT_H
```

dataobject.cpp

```
#include "dataobject.h"
DataObject::DataObject(QObject * parent): QObject(parent){}
DataObject::DataObject(const QString &_title,QObject * parent)
  :QObject(parent),m_title(_title)
{}
QString DataObject::title() const { return m_title;}
void DataObject::setTitle(const QString &title) {
    if ( title != m_title ) { m_title = title; emit info();}
}
```

Comment: This is far too much code for a Stack Overflow question.  Please edit it down to only the necessary part(s) with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i tried to be a short as posible please look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to do:

1. `Message` has to modify the model, therefore `Message` needs the instance of the model.
2. When model is changed, emits signal to QML so QML can reload data.

Assume that your `Message` class is responsible for the model. First, pass the model to `Message`.

```
class Message : public QObject {
    //...
private:
    QList<QObject *> *list;
public:
    void setListInstance(QList<QObject *> *dataList){ list = dataList; }
}

//main.cpp
msg.setListInstance(&dataList);
```

You can easily change the content of model now:

```
void Message::refreshLista(){ list->append(new DataObject("new")); /*whatever*/}
```

However, QML won't reload the model because `setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(dataList));` cannot emit signals. Remove this line from main.cpp and create a new property in `Message` instead:

```
class Message : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<QObject> myModel READ getList NOTIFY listChanged)
public:
    QQmlListProperty<QObject> getList();
signals:
    void listChanged();
}
```

In the implementation, [create a QQmlListProperty](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#properties-with-object-list-types) and emits property-changed signal when necessary.

```
void Message::refreshLista(){
    list->append(new DataObject("new"));
    emit listChanged();
}
QQmlListProperty<QObject> Message::getList(){
    return QQmlListProperty<QObject>(this, *list);
}
```

Finally, the ListView in QML should bind to `message.myModel` instead of `myModel`:

```
ListView {
    width: 400; height: 300;
    model: message.myModel
    //...
}
```